# Clicking All Buttons with Javascript on a Dynamically Loaded Page

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write a javascript code that click all the button in a discussion thread on https://www.teamblind.com/, so I can see all the comments without clicking buttons to expand them.

I found I can click all the buttons by doing the following

```
var bs = document.getElementsByClassName('btn_more');
bs[0].click();
```

in the console, I just have to repeatedly run bs[0].click(); until one element is left, but when I turned that into a while loop like the following

```
function clickall() {
var bs = document.getElementsByClassName('btn_more');
while (bs.length > 1 ) { // 1 because the last button directs to other page, all other buttons expands the contents in the current thread
bs[0].click(); 
}
  return;
}
```

the browser tab would actually stops working when I run this function in the web console, I had to use task manager to shutdown a browser process to stop this function running in the console.

One of my guess is that the page loads dynamically, and maybe I need wait for the page to expands? Does anyone know why the tab can hang from running such a function and how this should be fixed?

EDIT:
Clicking a button decreases the `bs` size
[image]

Logging the `bs` size

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: `bs.length > 1` is your while condition. It will run forever because the number will not change. Use `for()` instead I would imagine.

Comment: @MarkBaijens thanks that's my guess too. I've searched a bit on how to do that, but I don't think I have the proper knowledge to find the right keywords for it, would you mind enlightening me on how the keywords to search?

Comment: Searching *javascript for* would be a good idea. Also searching for *javascript getElementsByClassName* will certainly find you examples where people use the return value.

Comment: @PeterKrebs the size of `bs` actually decreases down to one when I manually run this in the console.

Comment: The size will be `> 1` for the first time you execute it and that will run forever. I don't think `bs` will update in the first run as you remove elements in later ones. In any case, `for` is certainly better suited here.

Comment: @PeterKrebs I added an image to prove that it decreases the length.

Comment: @PeterKrebs I actually tried `for` but it didn't work. My guess is that the elements dynamically disappear from the array.

Comment: That's not what I mean. The length will decrease in subsequent calls, but your first call should still run in the background forever. Put a `console.log(bs.length)` in your while loop to test that.

Comment: Also your code executes if the number of buttons is > 1. But what about the last one? Shouldn't it be `>= 1`?

Comment: @PeterKrebs I updated the question with an image with the results of console log, but it only seems to run once now somehow with two prints, and it still hangs. It's 1 because the last one button links outside of the current webpage.

Comment: Okay right, if you only run that from the console `bs` will update for the other running code as well. Still, in that case just write `if` instead of `while` is our point. You only want to run the code once, so why have a loop then?

Comment: @PeterKrebs No I want to run the function once, and have it click all the buttons. That's why I have a loop.

Comment: But you are not clicking them you are only clicking the first one. That's why I mentioned a for loop. I guess I'll demonstrate in an answer.

Answer (score 0):

the btn itself might not be removed after the click, it may have became invisible. And aside from that, the buttons have already been collected before the loop so if they get removed, this might be the reason the error is being caused, a node that can't be found is being applied a function. So instead use a `for...each` loop or query elements each time inside the while loop.

Comment: The button actually is removed and disappeared. I tried all for loop and query inside the loop, but didn't work.

Comment: @drerD can you share your for loop

Comment: I did what @peterkrebs did in his answer but it doesn’t work.

Answer (score 0):

So first the while loop is not needed. Let's do that with `if`:

```
function clickall() {
  var bs = document.getElementsByClassName('btn_more');

  // 1 because the last button directs to other page,
  // all other buttons expands the contents in the current thread
  if ( bs.length > 1 ) {
    bs[0].click(); 
  }
}
```

So we only click this button once. Now we can run that code regularly:

```
// You can stop the loop with window.clearInterval(intervalHandle); when you want.
let intervalHandle = window.setInterval(clickall, 500);
```

Further reading:

- [document.getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)
- [window.setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval)
- [window.clearInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/clearInterval)

Comment: This doesn’t work. I tried it. You can try running the code yourself

Comment: It’s not that simple, i don’t think you get this at all, the issue has to do with dynamic page loading. You keep focusing on the syntax or the function, which I don’t believe are right direction.

Comment: And clicking the first element works, you can see my prove in the image. It’s always clicking the 0th because the previous 0th button disappears. Then the next button becomes the 0th button.

Comment: Okay then I would still question why you use `while`. I'll change that to `if` then.